# How to create a radio button using only javascript (I don't want to use html tags)?

Tags: javascript, button, radio-button, khan-academy

I'm learning javascript over at Khan Academy and need help creating a radio type button. For this code, I'd prefer not using html tags.

I initially had an emoji that would move along with the mouseX and mouseY movements. However, after adding the button feature (which works), the emoji doesn't work. It seems to be an either or case. Is there a way I can re-order my code such that both work?

Basically I want an emoji that moves with mouseX and mouseY (X,Y positions of the mouse) and be able to add a button feature which adds a circle to either the top of the emoji or the bottom, depending on which button is clicked. I would like the emoji to still be capable of moving after the circle is added. The bottom two rectangles on the right are the buttons. The white circle is the Emoji and the background is a pink circle and pink blank screen.

I tried reordering the code with various combinations of the mouseClicked within the draw, or outside it or within the drawEmoji. But so far I haven't chanced upon a way that gives me what I am looking for. Is it possible to do this using purely javascript? TIA

**EDIT:**

- Here's the link to where I'm working on my code. I haven't put it in jsfiddle because I don't know how to use html tags and add code to it yet.
  https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-simple-buttons-with-functionsobject-params/4602551803707392
- As far as explaining what I would like to happen, that's in paragraph 3 of my post? Do let me know if it's not clear still.

Here's my code so far:

```
var x = 250;
var y = 300;
var btnwidth = 100;
var btnheight = 30;

//to highlight the button that is pressed
var highlightbox = function(hix, hiy, hiw, hih) {
 noFill();
 stroke(56, 247, 8);
 strokeWeight(5);
 rect(hix, hiy, hiw, hih);
};

//outer circle of the emoji face, the idea was for it to move along with the mouse but now it doesn't
var X = constrain(mouseX, 190, 210);
var Y = constrain(mouseY, 115, 140);
var W = 160;
var H = W;
var drawEmoji = function() {
    var X = constrain(mouseX, 190, 210);
    var Y = constrain(mouseY, 115, 140);
    var W = 160;
    var H = W;
    fill(247, 242, 242);
    stroke(0, 51, 255);
    strokeWeight(3);
    ellipse(X,Y,W,H);
};

//background behind the emoji
var drawBackground = function() {
 background(250, 187, 187);
 fill(191, 130, 130);
 stroke(255, 0, 0);
 strokeWeight(3);
 ellipse(200,200,400,400);

 fill(247, 207, 247);
 rect(x, y, btnwidth, btnheight);
 fill(173, 207, 250);
 rect(x, y+50, btnwidth, btnheight);

};

drawBackground();
drawEmoji();

var draw = function() {
 //mouse click function for the button, when it's clicked a circle appears on the emoji
 mouseClicked = function(){
    drawBackground();
    drawEmoji();

    if (mouseX > x && mouseX < (x + btnwidth) && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y + btnheight)) {
        highlightbox(x, y, btnwidth, btnheight);
        stroke(68, 0, 255);
        fill(247, 207, 247);
        ellipse(X - 49,Y - 50,W/3,H/3);
    }
    else if (mouseX > x && mouseX < (x + btnwidth) && mouseY > y + 50 && mouseY < (y + 50 + btnheight)) {
        highlightbox(x, y + 50, btnwidth, btnheight);
        stroke(68, 0, 255);
        fill(173, 207, 250);
        ellipse(X+1,Y+100,W/3,H/3);
    }

 };

};
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide an example of code working online, eg on http://jsfiddle.net, which would help us to help you

Comment: You fail to state in what way "it doesn't work" and how you expect it to work.

Comment: @JNF I've added a link now
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-simple-buttons-with-functionsobject-params/4602551803707392

Comment: @DavidHoelzer As far as explaining what I would like to happen, that's in paragraph 3 of my post? Do let me know if it's not clear still.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 6 months old, but I noticed on Khan that you haven't changed the code from what you posted here; so I assume you still might want to finish it.

I'm not going to give you specific code to fix it (that's your job!), but here are some pointers.

First of all, you need to move the mouseClicked function out of the draw function and remove the draw function completely. The draw function, when defined, is called continuously and is intended for animation even when no mouse action takes place. You currently only want to draw when some action with the mouse is taken. Drawing continuously is overkill!

Secondly, add a global variable to indicate if the circle must be drawn and, if so, top or bottom. In the mouseClicked function you mustn't draw the circle - just set this variable to what it should be and call your two draw functions for the background and the emoji.

Add a mouseMoved function to call your draw functions.

In your draw function for the emoji, test your global variable to decide where to draw the circle (or not to draw it).